# Labeling points using qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble labeling points in R.  I've created a qplot that uses four numeric variables I'm plotting as the x and y axes, the color of the points and the size of the points.  When I try to add the labels by just including label = player (where player is the column name with the labels I want) R says: "Error: object 'Player' not found."  Maybe because this is the only text column?  This is probably really simple, but my first plot, so...

Answer (score 0):

```
qplot(cars$dist, cars$speed) + geom_text(label = cars$dist)
```

You can append normal ggplot syntax to `qplot()` exactly the same way you would when calling `ggplot()`.

You need to specify the source of the data you are feeding: you can do so by passing the name of the dataframe to the data argument of a `geom()` and then referencing a specific column ('Player'), in quotes, in the `aes()` call within the same `geom()`:

```
geom_point(data = data, aes(x = 'col1', y = 'col2'))
```

or you can `attach()` the data, and then just specify the column (without quotes or the `data=` parameter):

```
geom_point(aes(x = col1, y = col2))
```

Thank you to [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222578/marius) for pointing out the notion that referencing data through the data parameter may be preferential over $ (data$col) in certain situations like facetting.

Comment: It's usually better to specify the `data` argument, and then not use `$` to access columns, in ggplot. It doesn't matter as much for simple examples like this, but it messes up things like faceting.

Comment: @Marius: it was fixed in recent [commit](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/9b640c5c98ed4f9aabd552038e59d977848ba72c)